# Is it possible to write as follows "to make a change from A to B"

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs

> This command changes (switches) a PC from a standby mode to a sleep
>   mode.

I am trying to describe this without an object "a PC". My example is as follows:

> This command makes a change from a standby mode to a sleep mode.

Is this acceptable?

Comment: Almost. To "make a change" fits better in other contexts, though, such as amending one's life. I would say "initiates a change" or "triggers a change" (at a glance, anyway. If we took the time we could probably write a more elegant sentence, but that'll do fine in my books...).

Comment: I second @LukeSawczak. _'Initiates'_ and _'triggers'_ sounds better as it has a hint of technicality associated with its usage, as you are talking about computers.

Comment: You might consider _"This command **toggles between** standby and sleep modes."_

Comment: What about using the verb "put": this command puts the computer into sleep mode.

Comment: Any verb is OK. I like the phrases "initiates a change" and "triggers a change" introduced by Luke. My question is that is the sentence not having the object "PC"  grammatically correct?

Comment: @P.E.Dant, will toggle be appropriate? Toggle would mean a back-and-forth action, which would not be true in the this context as the system cannot come back to a standby mode using the command.

Comment: @VarunKN Only the OP can answer that! But if there are only two states, _toggle_ is the most common verb.

Answer (score 2):

If the context makes it clear that you're talking about the PC, then you can omit the usage of '*PC*' in the sentence, as long as there is no scope for a confusion of what you're talking about.

In addition to that, you can also omit the '*a*' that precedes 'standby mode' and '*sleep mode*'.

Possible alternatives:

- > This command changes the mode from Standby to Sleep.
- > This command changes the state from Standby mode to Sleep mode.

Just a few suggestions. But all this depends on the wider picture of the context. So from what you have provided us with, we can only assume that you have made it clear to the reader that you are, indeed, talking about the PC itself.

Comment: The command's mode is not standby or sleep, so "its" doesn't work. But "the state" is probably understandable by the user.

Comment: @LukeSawczak, that's true. I overlooked that the sentence could also be interpreted as such.